# How many solutions can a non-homogeneous equation have with no free variables?

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation $Ax=b$ is non-homogeneous, meaning that $b \neq 0$

I also know that the linear system has no free variables. What is the number of possible solutions that the equation can have?

I think the answer is $1$, but I am not sure, can someone fact-check me?

Here is my reasoning

No free variables, means that there are no variables not in pivot columns (e.g. all columns are pivot columns) - so the augmented row-echelon form of $Ax=b$ would be something like

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} & b_1\\
0      & A_{22} & A_{23} & b_2\\
0      & 0      & A_{33} & b_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since we know there are 3 pivot columns, it becomes this

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & 0 & 0 & b_1\\
0      & A_{22} & 0 & b_2\\
0      & 0      & A_{33} & b_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since $A_{11} A_{22} A_{33}$ span $R^3$, there can only be one solution whatever $b$ is

Am I right?

Comment: Not sure I follow your definition of `no free variables`, but I don't see offhand how that excludes the case of $0$ solutions.

Comment: @dxiv no free variables implies all variables are basic, thus all variables are in a pivot column

Comment: Are any variables "*free*" in $x+y=1, x+y=2\,$? Pivot columns are an artifact of a method of solving linear systems, not an intrinsic property thereof.

Comment: @dxiv - yes, $y$ would not be in a pivot column in the augmented reduced row-echelon form. Therefore $y$ is free (Am I total shit at linear algebra? The number of points you have scare me that I am wrong) - I also dont understand what you mean by `Pivot columns are an artifact of a method of solving linear systems, not an intrinsic property thereof`

Comment: @dxiv thanks :)

Comment: P.S. Regarding pivots, they only come into picture as one technique to solve linear systems, among others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after checking with other sources, I am correct.

All non-homogeneous equations of the form $Ax=b$ with no free variables will have $1$ solution.